# Ubuntu IPV6 /48 routed over link-local

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ipv6

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 set up with with a /48 IPv6 routed to it.

According to the hosts documentation it's an expert only option, [described like this](http://support.arpnetworks.com/kb/main/what-is-the-difference-between-my-ipv6-64-assigned-space-and-48-allocated-space):

> For those customers, we will route the entire /48 block over a
>   link-local address (fe80::/64). This is standard practice (RFC 3177,
>   RFC 5375).

I have had other webservers with a /48 subnet, where adding new addresses is as simple as adding them to /etc/network/interfaces

I'm told my /48 is routed to fe80::2. Can someone explain what to do from here?

Comment: What does the rest of your network look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can either setup dhcpv6 (as I heard dibbler client is easy to use and perfect for that), or configure it as static (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6)

What you need to do is assign an address to your server and give the link local address as the default route to your system. Remove all other routes. 
If you are willing to use static configuration, disable these in your sysctl.conf: 
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0

or it will overwrite your route settings. (sysctl -p or restart afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is for a VPS on ARP Networks in case anyone ever googles this.

I had to set my local ipv6 to fe80::2 and my default gateway to fe80::1 making my ipv6 configuration in /etc/network/interfaces look like this

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address fe80::2
        gateway fe80::1
        netmask 48
```

With that in there I can assign and use any of the external IP's in my /48

Comment: I'd use `netmask 64` rather than `netmask 48`. If you want to be sure which IPv6 address will be visible in traceroute outputs, you need to pick one IPv6 address from your /48 and assign that address to eth0 as well with a netmask of 128.